# Inflating menu on multiple fragments with multiple toolbars

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a container that holds three different fragments, each one of them should change how the toolbar looks & behaves. So I put the toolbar in each of the`enter code here` fragments, which works seamlessly when switching from one to the other, but when inflating each fragment's menu on onCreateOptionsMenu they are not shown due to none of the toolbars being the main one associated with the activity.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
        this.menu = menu

        updateMenuItem(picks_viewpager.currentItem)
    }
```

How can I inflate these menus into each toolbar then?

Comment: You should use different layout for each fragment toolbar

Comment: this does not answer my question

Comment: Are you not seeing the menu items after changing to another fragment?

Comment: no im not, since i am calling    baseActivity?.setSupportActionBar(dashboard_fragment_toolbar)